# How can i get flutter list in list contains value and index

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a pagination, there are 10 shapes in it, a new list is passed when 10 is filled

```
List<List<Product>>
```

I want to check if there is a value in it, if there is, I want to get its index. For example, how do I know that I am 35 in the 3rd index of the first list and the 5th index of the list in it?

```
for (var lists in _allPagedResults) {
          exists = lists.any((result) => result.pid == id);
          index = lists.indexWhere((result) => result.pid == id);
          if (exists == true) {
            break;
          }
        }
        if (exists == true) {
          if (index != 0) {
            observerController.animateTo(
              index: _allPagedResults.length <= _productLimit
                  ? index
                  : _allPagedResults.length * _productLimit + index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
          }
        } else {
          _requestProduct(true, id);
        }
```

I'm doing with this code but I can't get the index right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, this should work. Please let me know if there are any issues.

```
int mainIndex = -1, subIndex = -1;

for (var el in lists) {
   ++mainIndex;
   subIndex = el.indexWhere((subel) => subel.pid == id);
   if (subIndex > -1) break;
}
```

now, if the element is found (`subIndex > -1`) then do the desired action:

```
if (subIndex > -1) {
   print("Id: $findId Index: $mainIndex SubIndex: $subIndex");
}
```